# The effect of time delay on the execution of PyQt5 QThreadPool()

Tags: python, pyqt5

Here is the scenario, I am using `QThreadPool` to execute different functions in parrallel. I have a list called `self.firstRun = []` and a function where this list is used in the following way.

```
def setdata(self):
  self.firstRun.append(1)
  print(self.firstRun)
  time.sleep(5)
```

this function is called by another function named `wait2` which is

```
def wait2(self):
   worker = Worker(self.setdata)
   self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

as can be seen the function `wait2` calls the class `Worker` and sends the function `setdata` to this class to be threaded. When I execute this program, I expect that the function `setdata` will give me `[1]` as output in first run and `[1,1]` in second and so on so forth. (I have included sleep only to read output clearly). But the problem is that when I execute this program it gives the following as output in first run.

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want the program to give `[1]` in first and then as it executes further, it should give me the list with one increment. Here is the complete code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import time
import numpy as np

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        result = self.fn(*self.args,**self.kwargs)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 800)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(19, 19, 300, 300))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget_2 = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 20, 300, 300))
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.widget_3 = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 20, 300, 300))
        self.widget_3.setObjectName("widget_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 420, 141, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 420, 141, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 490, 311, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 540, 61, 21))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 540, 61, 21))
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 540, 61, 21))
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.firstRun = []
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.data_line1 = self.widget.plot(self.x,self.y)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(10)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.wait2)
        self.timer.start()


        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()  

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Text"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

    def wait2(self):
        worker = Worker(self.setdata)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def setdata(self):
        self.firstRun.append(1)
        print(self.firstRun)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the last I must say, I used the `QThreadPool` portion of code from a website Learpyqt.com

**Edit 1**

When I detach the function `wait2` from `QTimer` and binds it to the button `pushButton_2` then every time I click the button, it gives the desired result. 
But I want it be attached with `QTimer` to get this function `setdata` update automatically.

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.wait2)
```

**Edit 2**

When I remove the sleep from setdata function then it works as I want. But as this program is part of my big project, where instead of time.sleep() I have multiple read functions which read data from other python files. This cause delay which I simply can't remove. So even if I remove time.sleep() in this case, It wouldn't solve my original problem.

**Edit 3**

I am reading multiple sensors, Pressure, Temperature, Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Magnetometer. The time of reading is different for each of these sensor. I prioritize Gyro, Accelerometer and Magnetometer to get maximum sample rate. When I read all sensors at once, the slowest of all these is temperature, so all sensors have to wait untill Temperature is read. Thus it reduces the sample rate of other sensors. That is why I introduced QThreading so that I can separate Temperature, Pressure from Accelerometer, Magnetometer, Gyroscope. Now, suppose I call the function (that hold Temperature and Pressure) every 10th ms, in such an order that It reads Temperature first and then Pressure, then it should maintain this order. But in my case it sometimes  override Temperature and move on to pressure, and sometimes read temperature for 10 times and then read pressure once. This irregular reading is the basic problem.

**Edit 4**

This is what I had done previously

```
self.timer_1 = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer_1.setInterval(1)
self.timer_1.timeout.connect(self.getValues)
self.timer_1.start()

self.timer_2 = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer_2.setInterval(10)
self.timer_2.timeout.connect(self.UpdatePlot_1)
self.timer_2.start()

self.timer_3 = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer_3.setInterval(10)
self.timer_3.timeout.connect(self.UpdatePlot_2)
self.timer_3.start()

def UpdatePlot_1(self):
    if self.Lstartbutton:
        self.plot_1.setData(self.t,self.temperature)
        self.plot_2.setData(self.t,self.pressure)

def UpdatePlot_2(self):
    if self.Lstartbutton:
        self.plot_3.setData(self.t,self.roll)
        self.plot_4.setData(self.t,self.rollDrift)
        self.plot_5.setData(self.t,self.rollAccel)


def getValues(self):
     if len(self.firstRun) <= 50:      
          self.firstRun.append(1)
          self.t         = np.arange(1,len(self.firstRun)+1)
          gyro2.updateGyroValues()
          gyro2.updateHeadings()
          xi,yi,xii,yii,zii,s1,s2    = gyro2.printHeadings()
          xiii,yiii,ziii = compass.axes()
          temperature    = sensor.read_temperature()
          pressure       = sensor.read_pressure()
          self.temperature.append(temperature)
          self.pressure.append(pressure)
          self.roll.append(xii)
          self.rollDrift.append(s1)
          self.pitch.append(yii)
          self.pitchDrift.append(s2)
          self.rollAccel.append(xi)
          self.pitchAccel.append(yi)

     else:
         self.t = list(self.t)
         self.firstRun1.append(1)
         self.t = self.t[1:]
         self.t.append(self.t[-1]+1)
         gyro2.updateGyroValues()
         gyro2.updateHeadings()
         xi,yi,xii,yii,zii,s1,s2 = gyro2.printHeadings()
         xiii,yiii,ziii = compass.axes()
         temperature = sensor.read_temperature()
         pressure    = sensor.read_pressure()
         self.temperature = self.temperature[1:]
         self.pressure    = self.pressure[1:]
         self.pressure.append(pressure)
         self.temperature.append(temperature)
         self.roll = self.roll[1:]
         self.pitch = self.pitch[1:]
         self.rollDrift = self.rollDrift[1:]
         self.pitchDrift = self.pitchDrift[1:]
         self.rollAccel = self.rollAccel[1:]
         self.pitchAccel = self.pitchAccel[1:]
         self.roll.append(xii)
         self.rollDrift.append(s1)
         self.pitch.append(yii)
         self.pitchDrift.append(s2)
         self.rollAccel.append(xi)
         self.pitchAccel.append(yi)
```

This approach read all sensors in same function. The sampling rate in this case if 9 readings/sec. When I remove Temperature and Pressure from this block
the sampling rate increase dramatically to 100 samples/sec. So I used the following solution (failed so far).

```
    self.timer_2 = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer_2.setInterval(1)
    self.timer_2.timeout.connect(self.thread_2)
    self.timer_2.start()

def getValues2(self):
    temperature    = sensor.read_temperature()
    pressure       = sensor.read_pressure()
    self.temperature.append(temperature)
    self.pressure.append(pressure)

def thread_2(self):
    worker = Worker(self.getValues2)
    self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

This made the reading of Gyro, Accelerometer and Magnetometer independent of Temperature and Pressure sensor. So now I can read much faster. But when I try to plot temperature and pressure against time. Then it fails because as I said earlier, the temperature and pressure are read in an irregular manner, which makes the length of the respective lists unequal thus cannot be plotted

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I don't think there is a "solution" if I take your requirements literally, but perhaps with my explanation of the problem you will explain in more detail what you want and thus offer you a workaround.</sub>

Previous knowledge:

- A [`QThreadPool`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html) can use a maximum number of threads that can be known through the [`maxThreadCount`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#maxThreadCount-prop) property, which in my case is 4 and I suppose that it is in yours as well, so if you try to start a [`QRunnable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html) and there are already 4 actives, then no it will start.
- Our eyes(brain) in very slow so the "prints" that take less than 30 ms would be printed as a block, and what happens if there are many blocks is it large? because our brain will unite those small blocks for what seems continuous. Conclusion: Our eyes are not a reliable tool for making measurements.

Considering the above, you are trying to start a runnable every 10 ms and each runnable stays practically active during the "sleep" time since the time consumed by the print is negligible so the active time is 5 seconds, so after 40 ms Once the program has started, no runnable will start and in that 40 ms our brain considers the 4 impressions as a block, and another runnable will only start after 5 seconds so it will observe the same effect.

Without "sleep" the 10 ms is a long time compared to the printing time, so when you want to start a new runnable I the number of threads will be 0 so the new thread will start and therefore the continuous printing is seen ( our brain deceiving us)

Comment: What this threading seems to be doing is that, when it sees time.sleep() ( which in real program will be a task)  it jumps over it, and execute the next command immediately, that should occur after time.sleep().

Comment: This very jump over time.sleep() to a next command has created the problem.

Comment: @Juno Let me explain: Let's say you are the boss of 4 workers and every day a new task comes to you, but each worker needs 10 days to do a task. What should happen with the fifth task if the workers are still busy with the previous task?

Comment: So it means I have to look for other alternatives?

Comment: @Juno No, you have to solve the problem that I pointed out in my previous comment that will solve the real problem. Your real problem is design, you want to do a lot of tasks but you don't have enough resources. Why is it necessary to start each runnable every 10 ms?

Comment: I read 'sensor A' data that I store in two variable, Temperature and Pressure. Reading these causes delay in whole GUI which affect another 'sensor B' reading. Thus I introduced QThreading to independently read both sensors.

Comment: So every time I call QRunnable, it reads sensor data, stores in respective list, then another QRunnable plots that data. The problem comes in plotting when it says, " X,Y dimensions do not match". This error occurs because. Temperature appends, with different rate, pressure with different rate and time with different rate. A type of mess is created.

Comment: For example, If reading Temperature and Pressure occur inside same function one after another. Then if I read Temp, it should wait till this reading is complete. And then move on to read pressure.

Comment: @Juno With your explanation it seems to me that you have a [XY problem] since instead of asking the underlying problem you ask about a possible solution: use threading. With the above I am not saying that the solution is not to use threading but that the solution could be another type of design.

Comment: @Juno On the other hand, your explanation is confusing so I ask you to answer all my questions: 1) If sensor "A" reads temperature and pressure, then what does sensor "B" read? 2) How often should each sensor be read? 3) How much time does it take to read each sensor? I asked my previous questions because I have worked with temperature sensors and the reading time takes very little time but it cannot be read from time to time, in my case the reading took a few milliseconds but it had to be read every 2 seconds.

Comment: @Juno To understand you need precise answers 1) How much time does each sensor consume in reading the information and how often do you have to read each sensor? 2) I do not understand why you indicate *Then it fails because as I said earlier, the temperature and pressure are read in an irregular manner, which makes the length of the respective lists unequal thus cannot be plotted* since according to the code and the explanation that you show you are only plotting the data and you are not doing any processing,

Comment: @Juno 3) If you are doing some processing then you should show it, on the other hand of my experience if my processing is Y = f (x1, x2) and x1 is read every T1, x2 is read every T2, and "f" is executed every T3 so the time of each processing must be T = max (T1, T2, T3), that is reading at t = 0 starts to read in 2 threads and only begins to process after both have finished reading

Comment: @Juno (if for example in t = 1 x1 was already read and t = 10 X2 was read then between t = 1 and t = 10 the sensor X1 should not do anything), and when the processing is finished, the reading starts (it can be read again after finishing the reading if T3 <<< max (T1, T2))

Comment: Did you see the read the update in question? I think it explains well the problem.

Comment: @Juno If I have read your update and therefore I ask my question since your wording is confusing, therefore I require precise answers to my numbered questions